# Which programming languages should one know to modify source code of SCRATCH

Tags: mit-scratch, block-programming

I intend to build a custom version of SCRATCH. I am a web-developer and hence not familiar with technologies that could have used to build scratch.

I see quite a lot technologies used in there such as Java Applets, C, SmallTalk and so on.

Can someone tell me the basic skill-set that's required to modify SCRATCH fro my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squeak is not a programming language. Looks like I need to know SmallTalk if I want to make changes and for more drastic changes I need to write C code.

Answer (score 3):

You should get the source code for Scratch: http://info.scratch.mit.edu/Source_Code

Comment: All it contains is one .changes file one .sources file and one .image file. It does not give me any clue where to start.

Comment: Read the information on the source code page, it tells you exactly what to do: "The download consists of a Squeak image and changes file. To view the source code, just drop the .image file onto a Squeak virtual machine (e.g. Scratch.exe or Scratch.app, which come bundled with Scratch). If you are new to Squeak, see the "Scratch and Squeak" section below."

Answer (score 0):

Scratch is written in squeak, which is a java implementation of smalltalk.

Comment: Squeak is "A Practical Smalltalk Written in Itself" and no "Java implementation of Smalltalk". See: [Back to the Future, The Story of Squeak, A Practical Smalltalk Written in Itself](http://ftp.squeak.org/docs/OOPSLA.Squeak.html)

Answer (score 0):

for 1.4, use squeak. for 2.0, use actionscript. 
if you want to mod 2.0, read http://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/38970/